# Omniauth user values return null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, session, omniauth

I am making an app with rails, [Rspotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify), and Angular. A user authenticates with Spotify, they search for music, add music to playlists (make playlists), and then that info is stored in PostgreSQL. I make an API on all of that data, and display it with Angular.

I have been able to get the music + music search functionality working fine. I am working to make a user and user model, but I am not doing something right when it comes to sessions and authenticating the user. I get redirected to the right path, and don't see any errors, but my code returns

```
{
"country": null,
"display_name": null,
"email": null,
"images": null,
"product": null,
"external_urls": null,
"href": null,
"id": null,
"type": null,
"uri": null
}
```

Here is my code;

**routes.rb**

```
root to: "home#index"

  #auth
  get '/auth/:spotify/callback', to: 'sessions#create', via: [:get, :post]

  resources :users

  get '/home', to: 'users#home'
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    # user's home, where current null data is
    def home
        @spotify_user = RSpotify::User.new
        render :json => @spotify_user
    end

    def music
        @music = RSpotify::Track.search(params[:search])
        render :json => @music
    end

end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        @spotify_user = RSpotify::User.new(:provider => auth['provider'],
                          :uid => auth['uid'].to_s) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
        reset_session
        redirect_to "/home", :notice => "Authenticated!"
    end

    #sign out
    def destroy
      session[:user_id] = nil
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed out!" 
    end
end
```

**users.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(auth.slice("provider", "uid")).first || create_from_omniauth(auth)
    end

    def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
        create! do |user|
            user.provider = auth["provider"]
            user.uid = auth["uid"]
            user.name = auth["info"]["nickname"]
        end
    end
end
```

I have also noticed that I do not receive a `uid` from Spotify. When I ran
`render :text => "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return`

in my `sessions#create`, it returned back info but the `uid` was blank. For reference, the only guide I have been able to use is [RailsCasts 241 Simple Omniauth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised). I have been having this problem for a while, and I know I am *sooooo* close to figuring it out because I finally have zero errors, and can see the data. If anyone has done something like this before and could point me in the right direction, I would be beyond grateful. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing your app's `User`s with the Spotify gem's `RSpotify::User`s.

When a user signs up with OmniAuth, you have to save it to the database. Then, in your UsersController, you have to find that user and send it as json.

Look at what you are doing here:

```
@spotify_user = RSpotify::User.new
render :json => @spotify_user
```

You are creating a new user (which has every single attribute as nil) and then you are rendering it as json.

Comment: thank you. So the sessions controller and user model have no interaction with Rspotify? It's just saving the rspotify user info in the DB? If I drop rspotify and make it `@spotify_user = User.new` and then leave the rest of my code as is? I'm sorry, I think I'm overcomplicating it...